# Select individual unique dialog for each option chosen

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-select, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to create a unique confirmation dialog that appears for each option selected. However currently I have it set so that the dialog will only appear if the option selected is less than the previously selected option. All seemed to be well on that front apart from the dialogs.

I have noticed that on alerts when I change to an option it is picking up the data-model attribute on each option but at times it doesn't trigger the correct dialog. (may have to keep flicking through to see it).

For example if I select the Mono option - the alert will show ('bus-outputs-reduce-width-to-mono) which is correct but then the dialog will show "reduce to Stereo".

The variations are different each time but I cannot figure out why it is doing this.

Also it would be good if the option didn't change until you have pressed confirm (although I know I wouldn't be able to use the .change function but not sure what else to us)

Any thoughts?

HTML

```
<select class="bus-width btn-light-outline" data-modal="fader-layout-new">
    <option value="No Path" data-modal="bus-outputs-remove-bus">No Path</option>
    <option value="Mono" data-modal="bus-outputs-reduce-width-to-mono" selected="selected" >Mono</option>
    <option value="Surround" data-modal="bus-outputs-reduce-width-to-stereo">Stereo</option>
    <option>5.1 Surround</option>
  </select>

<div class="overlay">

    <a class="cancel">Cancel</a>
    <a class="confirm">Confirm</a>

<div class="hide" id="bus-outputs-remove-bus">Remove Bus?</div>
<div class="hide" id="bus-outputs-reduce-width-to-mono">Reduce to Mono?</div>
<div class="hide" id="bus-outputs-reduce-width-to-stereo">Reduce to Stereo?</div>

</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var lastIndex = null;

$('select.bus-width').on('change', function () {

    var thisIndex = $(this).find(":selected").index();
    if(thisIndex < lastIndex){
        var myModal = $(':selected').attr("data-modal");
        alert(myModal);
        $('#' + myModal).stop().fadeIn(300);
        $('.overlay').fadeIn(300);
    }

    lastIndex = thisIndex;

});


$('.confirm').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').hide();
});
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
    z-index:99999;
}
.hide {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    top:200px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
    background:red;
}
.cancel {
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:270px;
    left:200px;
    padding:20px;
}
.confirm {
    background:yellow;
    position:absolute;
    top:270px;
    left:270px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/47a21r25/

Answer (score 1):

Please see [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/tac5tdux/).

I added the code below since I think you forgot to hide the other modals before showing the correct one.

**UPDATED JS**

```
    if (thisIndex < lastIndex) {
        var myModal = $(':selected').attr("data-modal");
        alert(myModal);
        $('.hide').hide();
        $('#' + myModal).fadeIn(300);
        $('.overlay').fadeIn(300);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this will fix the issue, or you could add $('.hide').hide() to $('.confirm').click() alongside the $('.overlay').hide() but either one works.

Comment: Thankyou! I cannot believe I missed this! I have spent hours trying to figure this out.